# No.of isomeric ethers of formula C3H6O

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, ethers

I managed to get 3 ethers:-
1.4-member ring ether(Oxetane)
2.Vinyl ether
3. Epoxy ether

This question was asked in my school exam and the teacher had given its answer as 4..Could anyone please tell what would be the 4th isomer ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methyl epoxy ether is chiral, with the chiral center being the middle carbon in the chain, so it has two enantiomers.